# Convert File to Binary using Javascript and C# Web

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to upload file to SQL Server database and download it again from web browser (any file: xlsx, pdf, etc).

Here is my HTML markup :

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="fileupload1" onchange="showname()" />
```

Javascript convert to binary :

```
            var filename;
            var contentType;
            var filestream;
            var fixarray;
            const fileByteArray = [];

            function showname() {
                var name = document.getElementById('fileupload1');
                filename = name.files.item(0).name;
                contentType = name.files.item(0).type;

                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(name.files[0]);
                reader.onload = function () {
                    filestream = reader.result;
                    fixarray = new Uint8Array(filestream);
                    for (let i = 0; i < fixarray.length; i++) {
                        fileByteArray.push(fixarray[i]);
                    }
                };
            }
```

My AJAX Call (events.id successfully called from other function) :

```
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "confirmationcomplete.aspx/finish",
                    data: '{ id: ' + JSON.stringify(events.id) + ',contentType: "' + contentType + '",name: "' + filename + '",binaryy: "' + fileByteArray + '"}',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('Success upload');
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);

                    }
                })
```

Backend code (C#) :

```
[WebMethod]
        
        public static void finish(int id, string contentType, string name, string binaryy)
        {
            string str = @"Data Source=172.16.111.45\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dashboard;User ID=sa;Password=sdfgh";
            SqlConnection cn2 = new SqlConnection(str);
            SqlCommand cmd7 = new SqlCommand("[sp_uploadfile]", cn2);
            cmd7.Parameters.Add("@eventID", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd7.Parameters["@eventID"].Value = id;
            cmd7.Parameters.Add("@contentType", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd7.Parameters["@contentType"].Value = contentType;
            cmd7.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd7.Parameters["@name"].Value = name;

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(binaryy);
            cmd7.Parameters.Add("@byte", SqlDbType.VarBinary,-1);
            cmd7.Parameters["@byte"].Value = byteArray;

            cmd7.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            try
            {
                cn2.Open();
                cmd7.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn2.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_uploadfile]  
    @eventID int,
    @contentType varchar(255),
    @name varchar(255),
    @byte varbinary(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO eventsScheduler 
    VALUES (@eventID, @contentType, @name, @byte)
END
```

From all of my code above, the upload file process to SQL Server database was successful.

But when I am trying to download it from browser, it throws an error

> Excel cannot open the file ... because the file format or extension is not valid

Button download :

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btndownload" OnClick="DownloadFile" CommandArgument="<%#hdID%>">Download Report</asp:LinkButton>
```

Here is my download code :

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(hdID.Value);
    byte[] bytes;
    string contentType, fileName;

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select  EventID,contentType,filename, report from [eventsScheduler] where EventID=@id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", a);
            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                sdr.Read();
                bytes = (byte[])sdr["report"];

                contentType = sdr["contentType"].ToString();
                fileName = sdr["filename"].ToString();
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }

    if (bytes.Length != 0)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = contentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

I assume the problem was at converting the binary from file upload in javascript code.

So I am trying to create one new upload control (using asp control) and try to upload the file directly :

ASP Control :

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload_NewProblem" runat="server" Width="100%" />
```

Button Upload :

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="Unnamed_Click">Upload</asp:LinkButton>
```

Button action :

```
protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            uploadFile();
        }
```

Backend Code :

```
public void uploadFile()
    {
        id = Convert.ToInt32(Request["id"]);
        int ids = id; // int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);

        string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload_NewProblem.PostedFile.FileName);
        string contentType = fileUpload_NewProblem.PostedFile.ContentType;
        using (Stream fs = fileUpload_NewProblem.PostedFile.InputStream)
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    string query = " INSERT INTO eventsScheduler VALUES (@eventID,@contentType,@name,@byte )";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventID", ids);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", filename);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contentType", contentType);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@byte", bytes);
                        try
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();

                            
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And when I upload the file using the second method (Without AJAX), I successfully downloaded the file using same download code.

My question is: how to convert file to binary using javascript in the same way with the C#?

Comment: Note: you're not really "converting" the file, you're just extracting the bytes from it. But why would you want to do that using JavaScript? It's much easier to just upload it in the way HTTP expects. Don't add extra complexity.

Comment: If you want to know how to upload files with jQuery AJAX, there are plenty of examples online of that already, and it's much simpler than your method

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thank you @marc_s. I removed all of my sp_ prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it.

I realized that Javascript converted my file to `string ("10,30,5,3")`.

So in server side I convert those `string` to `array` of `Int`

```
int[] array = binaryy.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

And then finally I convert those `array` of `int` to `array` of `byte`

```
byte[] bytes = array.Select(i => (byte)i).ToArray();
```